# JQuery .load() adds vertical tabs to the request uri in Opera 9.80

Tags: jquery, opera

I have written a jquery script to dynamically load a form on a web page:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#reserveringskeuze").change(onSelectChange);
});
function onSelectChange(){
var selected = $("#reserveringskeuze option:selected");     
var output = "";
    if(selected.val() != 0){
    output = selected.text();
}
if(selected.val() != 0){
$("#output").load("/reserveren/" + output)
$("#output").html(output);
}
}
</script>
```

This works well in most browsers, except Opera 9.80 (haven't test other opera versions). In most browsers request uri will be like /reserveren/bungalow/ in Opera the request uri becomes /reserveren/%09%09%09%09%09%09bungalow/ I don't know why those vertical tabs signs ( %09 ) are added.

Any idea?

Comment: Aside from the vertical tab issue you'll want to [encodeURIComponent(output)](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURIComponent.asp) when you add it to the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
output = $.trim(selected.text());
```

Looks like Opera is selecting the tabs.  Trimming it should remove the extra tabs.

Comment: trim() isn't supported by all browsers, use $.trim(selected.text()) instead.

Comment: No problem. If this answers your question, please mark it as answered.